# Google Maps JS API intermittently crashes process on custom marker click

Tags: javascript, performance, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, crash

I'm afraid the product I'm working on is so inherently full of esoteric client-sensitive stuff that I can't meaningfully reduce the problem scenario to a reproductible example, so this is appealing to domain expertise and insight, based on the following code:

http://jsbin.com/barney/1/edit

(makes use of jQuery, Underscore, Mustache, a few plugins and of course Google Maps v3 JS API)

I am using the Google Maps JS API to produce a relatively simple web app. So far all it does is create a custom content `InfoWindow`, dynamically changing the content as and when users click on custom `MarkerImage`s. The map is desaturated by use of stylers.

Intermittently (can't reliably reproduce) the process will completely freeze when I click one of these custom markers. I have a breakpoint on the first line of my code immediately within the `event.addListener` – the first time my code is hit in the usual stack of things – but the process never gets there: everything is frozen by the time I get there.

4 marker clicks usually does the trick, but other times the application will run through the entire UX without a fuss.

Additional info, off the top of my head:

- I have a couple of jQuery click events delegated to the body (not
  that these are firing in the observable stack);
- Left alone for 5 minutes or so, this app will freeze anyway, so I suspect I am unwittingly silently abusing the Maps API anyway.

Any advice on gotchas for this kind of scenario would be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you ran that code through a JS validator, e.g. jslint?  It picks up quite a few things that maybe could be tidied up.

Comment: Leading zeros, and integer coercion via double unary not… heh. I guess I /could/ clean up my style a bit… ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the above issues were resolved by removing CSS3 transitions from an ancestor element of the Google Maps DOM structure, which makes use of `translate3d(0)` as a hack to force GPU-accelerated animation. Bizarre but true. Tidbits of [anecdotal](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/issues/204) [evidence](http://forums.appmobi.com/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=1579&p=8050) from apparently unrelated performance issues in Webkit reveal that applying `transition`s to `translate3d`'d has all sorts of uncaught memory leak issues. Odd, considering conventional wisdom has it that applying translate3d to transitions is a way of relieving CPU performance hogging!

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue. My webapp crashes following no apparent pattern. Could you explain how did you remove CSS3 transitions?

Comment: By looking for them in my code and deleting the relevant lines.

Comment: So, it was just your own code that you modified. Google Maps library by itself has no such memory leak problem?

Comment: Yes — the problem was that the map existed inside an element with transitions.